# Adding Array to plist (I can not see more than only one item on my plist)

Tags: plist, codable, saving-data

```
import Foundation

struct answers : Codable {
    var answer : String
    var number : Int
}

var allAnswers: Array = [answers]()

let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
let archiveURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathExtension("answers_test").appendingPathExtension("plist")

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var vcLabels: [UILabel]!
    @IBOutlet weak var vcTextField: UITextField!
    var index : Int = 0
    @IBAction func vcButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
       vcLabels[index].text =  vcTextField.text
      var newAnswer = answers(answer: vcLabels[index].text!, number: index)

        var newAnswers = [newAnswer]
       print(archiveURL)
        index += 1

        if index == 4 {
            index = 0
        }

        let propertyListEncoder = PropertyListEncoder()
        let encodedNotes = try? propertyListEncoder.encode(newAnswers)
        try? encodedNotes?.write(to:archiveURL, options: .noFileProtection)


    }
```

Comment: when I open the plist I just see only the item last saved. I can not see all the items I try to save.

Comment: Please don't add information in the comments. [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50037935/edit).

Answer (score 0):

First of all please conform to the naming convention that struct and class names start with a capital letter, the benefit it that the struct `Answer` and the property `answer` cannot be mistaken. And to avoid more confusion name the struct in singular form (in the line where a new answer is created you are creating semantically **one** answer, not *one answers*). And the properties can be declared as constants (`let`).

```
struct Answer : Codable {
    let answer : String
    let number : Int
}
```

---

Your issue is very clear: If you want to append something to the property list file you have to **read** it first from `archiveURL`, append the item(s) and write it back.

```
@IBAction func vcButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    vcLabels[index].text =  vcTextField.text
    let newAnswer = Answer(answer: vcLabels[index].text!, number: index)
    print(archiveURL)
    index += 1

    if index == 4 {
        index = 0
    }

    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: archiveURL)
        var savedAnswers = PropertyListDecoder().decode([answers], from: data)
        savedAnswers.append(newAnswer)

        let encodedNotes = try PropertyListEncoder().encode(savedAnswers)
        try encodedNotes?.write(to:archiveURL, options: .noFileProtection)
    } catch { print(error) }

}
```

And don't ignore errors with `try?`. **Handle them**